# Converting measurements in a form to update a table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am using Access 2010 to create a database of fish caught by local fishermen.  I have a table with all the information about each fish caught (location, day, length, etc) and a form to add new records to that table.  I am trying to automate as much of the data entry as possible because we have many interns that will be entering data throughout the summer. The more I can have the program do, the more I can limit mistakes in data entry.

I would like to store the length data in metric (mm), however most of the fishermen report the lengths of the fish they catch in inches.  I don't care to have length twice in my database, one metric and one imperial.

Is there a way I can have a box on the form that someone can enter the length in inches and this value is converted to metric and used to fill in the length field on the table?  The trick is that sometimes the fish length is reported in metric, so I need to be able to directly input metric into the form too.

I'm guessing this is either not possible or already somewhere & I am not using the right key words in my searches. I  appreciate anyone who can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. It's similar to Scotch's, but with a few enhancements.

Have 2 textboxes. 1 each for millimeter & inch sizes.
The Milimeters textbox is bound to the table through the Control Source, so what is entered in there is what is saved in the database.
The Inches textbox is unbound. But what is entered into that textbox is converted and the new value is put into the Millimeter textbox. The code would look like this:

```
Private Sub txtSizeIn_AfterUpdate()
   Me.txtSizeMM = Me.txtSizeIn * 25.4
End Sub
```

This way, the fisherman will have a choice on what measurement to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Tom.  This worked perfectly! I knew there had to be an easy way to do this, but I couldn't put my thumb on it or find the right key words to search.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In the `After Update` for your control in which the measurement is entered, say the control is called `Length`.

You can change it in vba with this code.

`Me.length = me.length * 25.4`

This is one of many ways to do this